# Changing background color of all elements within div on hover

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to achieve the following behavior:
I am working on a search bar with functionality to add filter options and search by the input, I am having troubles styling the hover effect properly.
When user hovers over any element within search bar the background color should change. The background color shouldn't change when user is focused on the input field and hovers over it.

```
'use client'
import React, { ChangeEvent, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import SearchIcon from '@/public/icons/applicationIcons/SearchIcon';
import FilterIcon from '@/public/icons/applicationIcons/FilterIcon';
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from 'next/navigation';
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';
import ArrowLeft from '@/public/icons/vectors/ArrowLeft';
import CancelIcon from '@/public/icons/applicationIcons/CancelIcon';
import FilterOptionsModal from './FilterOptionsModal';
import { FilterOptionModalType } from './FilterOptionsModal';
import useClickOutside from '@/app/hooks/useClickOutside';

export type SearchProps = {
  onSearch: (value: string, filterOptions?: any) => void;
  filterOptionNames: FilterOptionModalType; // Add filterOptionNames prop
};

const SearchBar = (props: SearchProps) => {
  const { onSearch, filterOptionNames } = props;
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [showFilterOptions, setShowFilterOptions] = useState(false);
  const [selectedFilterOption, setSelectedFilterOption] = useState<any>(null);
  const searchFilterRef = useRef(null)

  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const { replace } = useRouter();

  const handleFocus = () => {
    setIsFocused(true);
  };

  const handleBlur = () => {
    setIsFocused(false);
  };

  const handleMouseEnter = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  const handleSearch = useDebouncedCallback((term: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { target } = term;
    setValue(target.value);
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    if (term) {
      params.set('query', target.value);
    } else {
      params.delete('query');
    }
    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
  }, 300);

  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      onSearch(value, selectedFilterOption);
    }
  };

  const handleCancelIconClick = () => {
    setValue('');
    setIsFocused(false);
    setSelectedFilterOption(null);
  };

  const handleFilterIconClick = () => {
    setShowFilterOptions(!showFilterOptions);
  };

  const handleFilterOptionSelect = (option: any) => {
    setSelectedFilterOption(option);
    setShowFilterOptions(false);
    onSearch(value, option); // Apply the selected filter option to the search
  };

  useClickOutside({
    ref: searchFilterRef, onClickOutside: () => {
      setShowFilterOptions(false)
    }
  });

  return (
    <div className={`relative flex w-[412px] h-[56px] rounded-full group ${isFocused || value ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : 'bg-white'} hover:bg-[#ededed]` } >
      <div className="flex w-full">
        <button onClick={handleBlur} className={`p-2 rounded-l-full ${isFocused ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : ''}`}>
          {isFocused ? <ArrowLeft /> : <SearchIcon />}
        </button>
        <input
          // ... (other input props)
          className={`pl-2 focus:outline-none w-full placeholder:text-[#49454F] hover:bg-[#ededed] ${isFocused || value ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : ''}`}
          placeholder="Caută un vehicul, şofer, număr..."
          value={value}
          onFocus={handleFocus}
          onChange={handleSearch}
          onBlur={handleBlur}
          onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
          onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter} // Add onMouseEnter to input for hover effect
          onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave} // Add onMouseLeave to input for hover effect
        />
        <button
          onClick={isFocused ? handleCancelIconClick : handleFilterIconClick}
          className={`p-2 rounded-r-full ${isFocused ? 'bg-[#ece6f0]' : ''} `}
        >
          {isFocused || value ? <CancelIcon /> : <FilterIcon />}
        </button>
      </div>

      {showFilterOptions && (
        <FilterOptionsModal
        ref={searchFilterRef}
          filterOptions={filterOptionNames}
          onFilterOptionSelect={handleFilterOptionSelect}
          height={203}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default SearchBar;
```

I have tried playing around with isHovered state and group class from Tailwind, but unfortunately neither of them gave me the behaviour I wanted.